# Is there a way to prevent inbox from clearing new notifications?

Tags: support, global-inbox

New notifications in the inbox are highlighted, but this highlight disappears as soon as the inbox is closed

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

My current process of reading notifications is:

1. Open each in a new tab (usually results in duplicated tabs with the same question)
2. Hope that I won't close any of these by accident
3. Read/react to each of them
4. If I don't have time to take care of one - save it (and most likely forget about it forever)

Is there a hidden option that I don't know of which allows one to somehow mark a notification as done?

Comment: Not yet, but there's a new inbox coming soon:tm: that does deal with this

Comment: [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread, and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/348196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm replying to this as an answer in order to afford the questions to be closed by the author.

Repeating what Zoe said and 41686d6564<sup>?</sup> informed, a new inbox that supports read/unread and filters should be available soon.

As detailed here: [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread, and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/348196)

Comment: I wanted to close it as a duplicate, but the original post is on a different site of the network